# open image from gallery using FileProvider

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I try to download image then save it to gallery then view it by using `VIEW_ACTION` by the help of `FileProvider` and all is good but when I tried to view image it show "photo can't load"

here how I create file

```
 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), SUB_DIR);
                if (!f.exists()) {
                    f.mkdirs();
                }
                String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
                DownloadRequestModel model = new DownloadRequestModel(image.id, PrefUtils.getBrandToken(getApplicationContext()));
```

and here is how i added to gallery

```
 public static Uri galleryAddPic(Context context, String currentPhotoPath) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    return contentUri;
}
```

and here is how i try to build my intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                Uri rightUri = BitmapUtils.galleryAddPic(getApplicationContext(), path + "/" + fileName);

                                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext()
                                        , getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", f);
                                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

but i found that the uri generated from gallery different from generated from file provider

genereted from gallery : file:///storage/emulated/0/PhlogBusiness/1597680349517.jpg
generated from file provider : content://com.example.ddopik.phlogbusiness.provider/external_files/PhlogBusiness

and here is my file provider path

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
```

so i am not sure what's wrong should i change file provider path or is there another way to open image from gallery

whole class code

```
public class DownloaderService extends Service {

private static final String SUB_DIR = "PhlogBusiness";

public DownloaderService() {
}

public static final String TAG = UploaderService.class.getSimpleName();

public static final int DOWNLOAD_FILE = 0;

private NotificationFactory notificationFactory = new NotificationFactory();
private int downloading;
private int failedDownloadsCount = 0;
private int totalDownloadCount = 0;

private Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new Handler(message -> {
    switch (message.what) {
        case DOWNLOAD_FILE:
            if (message.obj instanceof BaseImage) {
                BaseImage image = (BaseImage) message.obj;
                downloading++;
                String fileName = new Date().getTime() + "." + image.extension;

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/" + SUB_DIR + "/" +fileName);
                if (!f.exists()) {
                    boolean j = f.mkdirs();
                    int x =9;
                }
                String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
                DownloadRequestModel model = new DownloadRequestModel(image.id, PrefUtils.getBrandToken(getApplicationContext()));
                String s = new Gson().toJson(model);
                String encryptedS = null;
                try {
                    encryptedS = Utilities.encrypt(s
                            , new SecretKeySpec(BuildConfig.PAYMENT_SECRET.getBytes(), "AES")
                            , BuildConfig.PAYMENT_IV_KEY);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
                String url = String.format(BaseNetworkApi.BASE_IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_URL + "/[%1$s]/download", encryptedS);
                totalDownloadCount++;
                handleNotification(null);
                Rx2AndroidNetworking.download(url, path, fileName)
                        .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                        .build()
                        .startDownload(new DownloadListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDownloadComplete() {
                                downloading--;
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);


                                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext()
                                        , BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", f);
                                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext()
                                        , (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                                handleNotification(pendingIntent);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.download_complete, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                checkAndStop();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(ANError anError) {
                                downloading--;
                                failedDownloadsCount++;
                                handleNotification(null);
                                checkAndStop();
                            }
                        });
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}));

private void handleNotification(PendingIntent action) {
    String message = getString(R.string.download_complete);
    if (downloading == 0) {
        if (failedDownloadsCount > 0) {
            message = getString(R.string.download_failed, failedDownloadsCount);
        }
        totalDownloadCount = failedDownloadsCount = 0;
    } else {
        message = getString(R.string.downloading_n_files, downloading);
    }
    notificationFactory.changeNotificationPendingIntent(getApplicationContext()
            , getString(R.string.permanent_notification_channel_id)
            , getString(R.string.permanent_notification_id), action
            , message, R.drawable.phlog_logo_yellow);
}

private void checkAndStop() {
    if (downloading == 0 && bound == 0) {
        stopForeground(false);
        stopSelf();
    }
}

private int bound = 0;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    bound++;
    return messenger.getBinder();
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    bound--;
    checkAndStop();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    notificationFactory.createNotificationChannel(getApplicationContext()
            , getString(R.string.permanent_notification_channel_id)
            , getString(R.string.permanent_notification_channel_name)
            , getString(R.string.permanent_notification_channel_desc));
    Notification notification = notificationFactory.createNotification(getApplicationContext()
            , getString(R.string.permanent_notification_channel_id)
            , R.drawable.phlog_logo_yellow
            , getString(R.string.phlog_downloading)
            , null, false, null);
    startForeground(Integer.valueOf(getString(R.string.permanent_notification_id)), notification);
}
```

}

Comment: `f.mkdirs();` Check the return value as it might fail. Dont continue if it fails.

Comment: I have the image in my gallery the problem only i can't load it

Comment: `new File(currentPhotoPath)` What is currentPhotoPath? And where does it come from?

Comment: `Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);`. Ehhhh.. that looks mote like a file scheme. No content scheme.

Comment: `i found that the uri generated from gallery` Where does the 'gallery' generate an uri? Which variable are you talking about?

Comment: currentPhotPath generated from f.getAbsulatePath()

Comment: `here how I create file` Sorry but that code does not create a file. And sorry again: i cannot follow your code. Too much steps missing.

Comment: You have twice a variable f. The first one is a directory. I cannot follow you. Please edit your post so we know what you do.

Comment: doesn't create file! !